# Change My Documents folder name in Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, localization

I have Wine with Play on Linux on my Ubuntu PC. I need to launch BYOND app, but the problem is that it requires all folder names not to have any Unicode symbols. Due to my system being in russian language the Documents folder is named in russian. How can I change the Documents folder name without reinstalling the whole setup?

Comment: Have you tried creating are hard-link that is named in english called `Documents`?

Comment: That won't work. System would just use Documents folder according to it's locale